# Identifying duplicates within a table: looking for query advice

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

So I am trying to identify duplicated contact records within an account, and looking for the best way to do this. There is a an account table, and a contact table. Below is the query I've come up with to give me what I need, but I feel like there is probably a better/more efficient way to do this, so looking for any feedback/advice. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT * FROM sysdba.CONTACT a WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL FROM sysdba.CONTACT b WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND a.ACCOUNTID = b.ACCOUNTID AND a.FIRSTNAME = b.FIRSTNAME AND a.LASTNAME = b.LASTNAME AND a.EMAIL = b.EMAIL
)
ORDER BY ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL
```

Here is another way I can do this, but having to use DISTINCT seems ugly..

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.CONTACTID, a.FIRSTNAME, a.LASTNAME, a.EMAIL FROM sysdba.CONTACT a WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN sysdba.CONTACT b WITH(NOLOCK)
ON a.ACCOUNTID = b.ACCOUNTID AND a.FIRSTNAME = b.FIRSTNAME AND a.LASTNAME = b.LASTNAME AND a.EMAIL = b.EMAIL AND a.CONTACTID != b.CONTACTID
ORDER BY a.CONTACTID, a.FIRSTNAME, a.LASTNAME, a.EMAIL
```

When checking the execution plans for both, the first query is 37% compared to 63% in the second query, which is surprising, as I've always though (apparently wrong) that using joins is quicker than relying on a where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite common practice, when you trying to identify duplicates, is to use windowed aggregate functions, such as `COUNT() OVER (...)` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)`.

Below is the query that should return you groups of records, where there are more than one `CONTACTID` for the same `ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL` combination. In other words this query returns records, having duplicates, along with their duplicates:

```
;WITH cteCONTACT
AS (
    SELECT ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTACTID,
        CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL)
    FROM sysdba.CONTACT
)
SELECT ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTACTID
FROM cteCONTACT
WHERE CNT > 1;
```

And the following query should return duplicates only, without records that they duplicates are:

```
;WITH cteCONTACT
AS (
    SELECT ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTACTID,
        NUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL
            ORDER BY CONTACTID)
    FROM sysdba.CONTACT
)
SELECT ACCOUNTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTACTID
FROM cteCONTACT
WHERE NUM > 1;
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know count over() was a thing, as I've only used row/rank over. Thanks!

Comment: Should I take into consideration that the first query I posted is faster than yours, or is it more typical to evaluate usefulness over query execution time when they are more or less the same?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that your queries appear to bring in records with null emails, where mine doesn't due to ansi nulls (and thus a need for isnull function), so that's good to note and a difference worth considering. Thanks!

Comment: @parrotsnest, in addition to examining query plan don't neglect using profiler or simple instructions like `set statistics time on` and `set statistics io on` to check actual query performance, because of query cost estimation is not always accurate. Also, if you check execution plans, you may notice, that your queries access `sysdba.CONTACT` twice, and, thus, likely are more IO consuming, where as both queries above access table once, but may take more CPU, without proper indexes. So, depending on your real data and indexes, test different approaches and choose what better suits your case.